# Удалить аудио из массива

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня игра в которой 8 карточек .Звучит рандомное аудио из массива, я кликаю на карточку ,и если аудио из массива совпадает с аудио файлом из карточки, то аудио из массива удаляется и звучит следующее,и так до тех пор пока массив не будет пуст. Данный код ,при угадывании карточки, не выкидывает аудио из массива,а повторяет тоже аудио что звучит изначала. Что тут нужно исправить?

```
               let gameContainer = document.querySelector('.game__container');
               let containerItem = document.querySelectorAll('.container__item')
               let randomAudio;

               function randomInteger(min, max) {
                 let rand = min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min);
                 return Math.floor(rand);
               }

               gameContainer.addEventListener('click', playGame);

               function playGame() {
                 const arr = Array.from(audios);
                 let index = randomInteger(0, arr.length - 1);      
                 randomAudio = arr[index];
                 if(randomAudio.play()){
                   arr.splice(index,1);
                 }
               containerItem.forEach((a)=>a.addEventListener('click',guessCard));
               function guessCard() {
                 if(randomAudio == this.querySelector('.audio')) {
                   this.style.opacity = '0.3';
                   starContainer.appendChild(createElement());
                   randomAudio.play();
                 }
                 else{
                   audioFail.play();
                   starContainer.appendChild(createFailElement());
                 }}

                 if(arr.length == 0){
                   document.querySelector('.game__over').style.display = 'block';
                  }
                 }
```

Comment: `audios` - ? *(2 символа нужно...)*

Comment: let audios = document.querySelectorAll('.audio');
Забыл вставить)

Comment: не помогло,мне кажется проблема вот в этом блоке
                   if(randomAudio == this.querySelector('.audio')) {
                   this.style.opacity = '0.3';
                   starContainer.appendChild(createElement());
                   randomAudio.play();
                 }